# Unable to redirect to a new URL on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following inside my web page:-

```
<select id="customernames">
//options goes here
</select> 
<button id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button" >Home</button>
<script>
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function ()
{
var siteurl = $("#customernames").val()
alert(siteurl);       
window.location.href = siteurl;
};
</script>
```

what i am trying to do is to redirect to a new url (new web page), when i click on a button , and the URL will be an option value inside a select list.
now currently i am able to get the URL value correctly,, but i am being redirected to the current page when i click on the button, so seems `window.location.href = siteurl;` will ignore the `siteurl` and just redirect to the current page. so can anyone advice ?

Comment: I can't see the full code, but I would bet it is submitting your form. If you do not specify an `action` tag, it is the current page by default.

Try to add an (e) inside the onclick function: `document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function (e) {`

Then do `e.preventDefault();` above the `alert(siteurl);`. This will prevent any other action (like submitting the form)

Comment: @Kamae yes worked well ...

Comment: @Kamae if you can add your answer, so i can accept it as an answer.

Comment: No worries mate, as @SevaKalashnikov told you another valid way to do it, plus he mentioned me, it is fine for me if you want to accept his answer. Many thanks though, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

Jquery `click` event can be used with `return false` to prevent the form submission

```
$(function() {

    $('#myButton').click(function() {
        window.location.href = $("#customernames").val();

        return false;
    });

});
```

Or as @Kamae mentioned you can just add `e.preventDefault();` to your current function